# Map<Class<?>, Object> registry

Tags: java, generics, collections, guava

I need to put test values in a class, somehow like in this simplified example:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
public class TestVal {
  private static Map<Class<?>, Object> dummyValues = Maps.newHashMap();
  static {
    dummyValues.put(String.class, "Banana");
    dummyValues.put(Integer.class, 42);
  }
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  static final <T> T ofType(Class<T> type) {
    return (T) dummyValues.get(type);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<? extends Object> list =
        Lists.newArrayList(ofType(String.class), ofType(Integer.class));
    for (Object object : list) {
      System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", object, object.getClass().getName());
    }
  }
}
```

which, once run, gives me:

```
Banana: java.lang.String
42: java.lang.Integer
```

so it's fine as a "basic" system.

I'd like more type-safety though.

I was trying to study Guava's `ImmutableClassToInstanceMap` but... I find it a little difficult, take a look at this method signature:

```
public static
    <B, S extends B>
        ImmutableClassToInstanceMap<B>
            copyOf(
                Map<? extends Class<? extends S>,
                ? extends S> map
            )
```

brutal, isn't it? How would I use it for "any" type? Did not see an example on Google's Wiki..

Can I move "one step up" without "going all the way" like the thing above? Am I missing another obvious way to do the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eh?  All you need to do with `ImmutableClassToInstanceMap` is something like

```
ImmutableClassToInstanceMap<Object> map = ImmutableClassToInstanceMap
  .builder()
  .put(String.class, "foo")
  .put(Integer.class, 42)
  .build();
```

and then you just call `map.getInstance(String.class)` to get out a `String`.

The generics on `copyOf()` are complicated but necessary, but for this case you'll almost certainly want to just use the builder instead.

Comment: there is no doubt your code is of high quality and I am the dummy myself for not understanding it... but... how about more examples on the wiki? Just to share some of your googly coolness with the world, care to actually _explain_ (briefly :)) what's happening in that Generic line? Particularly, why do you take <B> at the end of ImmutableClassToInstanceMap when that's not used explicitly, that I can see (I have narrow vision obviously here).

Comment: Let me upvote you just because of the sheer awesomeness of Guava, for which I am very thankful!!

Comment: My "guess" is that "maybe" sometimes one wants to be explicit about an upper bound of Class<?> objects the Map will contain so as to be more "type-safe" when extracting instances from the (now typed) bucket?

Comment: Yup.  `B` is just the upper bound on the types stored in the `ClassToInstanceMap`.  I added some more explanation in [the wiki](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#ClassToInstanceMap).

Comment: You _did_ extend the wiki in real time? Flippin' heck, dude... that's amazing... (!!!)

Comment: Fantastic: ImmutableClassToInstanceMap removes the need to suppress type safety warnings, exactly what I needed.